# Stack numpy arrays in 4th dimension inside a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, stack

I would like to stack numpy arrays with the dimension `(2,9,38)` inside a loop along a new axis to create an array having the dimension `(2,9,38,x)`. Here x is the number of array stacked together. If I use np.stack I get the error massage:

```
all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Numpy is able to stack the first two arrays, but then it strikes to add a third one since now the already stacked ones have a different dimension. Now I wonder whether there is an option to stack arrays over each other in a loop. 
Here is the entire code section which I used:

```
Pint_data = np.load(f'{files_npy[0]}')
for i in range(len(files_npy)-1):
   Pint_data_temp = np.load(f'{files_npy[i+1]}')
   print(Pint_data_temp.shape, i)
   Pint_data = np.stack((Pint_data, Pint_data_temp))
```

Thanks in advande for your answers!

Comment: Do not use `stack` repeatedly in a loop!  Using any of the `concatenate` family in a loop is inefficient, but `stack` is worse - it adds a dimension each time.  You don't want that.  Please pay close attention to dimensions when using this category of functions.  It is best to collect results in a list, and do one `stack/concatenate` at the end

Comment: Hi hpaulj, I saw your answer but unfortunately forgot to reply to it. It was helpful, thank you! I did not think about adding arrays to a list to stack them at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

A simple list append approach:

```
alist = []
for i in range(len(files_npy)):
   Pint_data_temp = np.load(f'{files_npy[i]}')
   print(Pint_data_temp.shape, i)
   alist.append(Pint_data_temp)
data = np.stack(alist)
```